# Feature Selection for Random Forest Regressor

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, random-forest, feature-selection

I am trying to train a Random Forest Regressor from sklearn. The Features I want to train on are of different types, numeric continuous, numeric categorical, textual categorical(name/nationality), latitude and longitude.

What I want to know is given all the features, how do I determine the most useful feature set to train my Random Forest Regressor?

Answer (score 3):

First, run your random forest model on data.

```
rf= RandomForestRegressor()
rf.fit(train_data,train_labels)
```

Then use **feature importance** attribute to know the importance of features from where you can filter out the features.

```
print(rf.feature_importances_)
```

And again run your model on selected features.

There are many more techniques you can use like correlation, pca etc. Having a domain knowledge also gives you an edge while building a model.

Comment: It should be rf.fit(train_data, train_labels), not test data.